# Change Listview Item background programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I was wondering how you can change the `listview` item background color.
Let's say I am making a chat application, this chat application will display messages for the sender and receiver. I want to know if it is possible to change the background image of each individual message based on who sent it. If the message was sent from me it would have a different background then if it was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Implement your own `ListAdapter` and implement the `getView()` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The way to edit every row of your listview in android is :

1- define your desired layout for a row as an xml layout file - e.g your rows can contain any number of UI widgets like TextView , EditText , ImageView ,....

2- Create a class called [yourListAdapter] - This class usually extends ListAdapter,Array Adapter, BaseArrayAdapter , .... Whatever class you choose to extend, you should implement a getView() method. In this method you inflate the layout you've just created in step 1 and set any number of properties like TypeFace, Background, ....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MessageEntity item = (MessageEntity) getItem(position);
    CollectHolder holder = null;
        String sender = item.getSender();
        String userId = Data.getUserData().getMid();
        if (!sender.equals(userId)) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.adapter_msg_left, null);
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_msg_right,
                    null);
        }
    holder = new CollectHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    fillData(holder, item, position);
    return convertView;
}
```

R.layout.adapter_msg_left and R.layout.adapter_msg_right is different background .